# Standalone Spring JtaTransactionManager not working with WAS

Tags: spring, jta

I am trying to use Spring JtaTransactionManager (WebSphereUowTransactionManager) in a standalone program with WAS9.0. The JndiTemplate is retrieved with a Jndi lookup and set to the spring JtaTransactionManager. The dataSource and JMS resources which are XA complaint are also retrieved from a Jndi lookup to the server. The problem I face here is that the operation performed in the transaction block is getting committed immediately . Looks like the resources are not managed by the transaction manager. The client program has all the WAS runtimes libraries in the classpath

Appreciate if anyone could help here and guide how we could make WebSphereUowTransactionManager work from outside a container.

```
applicationContext_Jta.xml:
<bean id="jndiTemplateLookUp" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate"> 
    <property name="environment"> 
        <props> 
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">iiop://ip:port</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory</prop>
        </props>
    </property> 
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplateLookUp"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/WSDataSource"/>
</bean>    

Main Code:
DefaultTransactionDefinition transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
ApplicationContext jtaApplicationCtx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext_Jta.xml");
JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = (JndiTemplate) jtaApplicationCtx.getBean("jndiTemplateLookUp");
DataSource datasource = (DataSource) jtaApplicationCtx.getBean("dataSource");



JtaTransactionManager transactionManager = new WebSphereUowTransactionManager();
transactionManager.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate);
transactionManager.afterPropertiesSet();



((CallbackPreferringPlatformTransactionManager) transactionManager).execute(transactionDefinition,
                new TransactionCallback<Integer>() {
 @Override
 public Integer doInTransaction(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {

 //DB SQL Execute

 //JMS Send

 return 0;
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also had problems with this TransactionManager with Liberty Websphere. I ended up forcing the DataSourceTransactionManager manually, like this:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager(final DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}
```

To me it seems like this functionality is either incompatible with newer versions of websphere, or that it's just plain broken.